# Как сделать чтобы автоматически менялся цвет comboBox при изменении позиции?

Tags: c#, winforms

**ИСПОЛЬЗУЕТСЯ:**  С#, Windows forms

**ИМЕЕТСЯ:**
    Имеется comboBox, который содержит список из:
        - Поз 1;
        - Поз 2;
        - Поз 3;

**ВОПРОС**
    1. Как сделать, чтобы при изменении позиции изменялся цвет combobox? 
    Т.е. если в combobox отображается
        - Поз 1, то цвет combobox  меняется красный;
        - Поз 2, то цвет combobox меняется жёлтый;
        - Поз 3, то цвет combobox меняется зелёный;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот стартовая точка

```
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (comboBox1.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                comboBox1.BackColor = Color.Red;
                break;
            case 1:
                comboBox1.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                break;
            case 2:
                comboBox1.BackColor = Color.Green;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Дальше доведете до ума сами, если возникнут проблемы - отвечу утром

Comment: То, что надо. Небольшой вопрос.
У меня предполагается несколько comboBox.
comboBox Тип 1 - 3 шт
В которых будет прописано:
- Поз 1;
- Поз 2;
- Поз 3;
Для всех трёх штук нужно прописывать аналогичный код 
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         // код 
        }
private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         // код 
        }
private void comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         // код 
        }
или можно как-то обобщить?

Comment: @koverflow, еще одно маленькое замечание, вместо подписки на одно событие из разных контроллов, лучше для удобства последующего сопровождения обработку оформить в виде отдельной функции, а ее уже вызывать в обработке событий.

Comment: @koverflow, если Вас устроил мой ответ, то пожалуйста отметьте, его как принятое решение.